# Self-signed certificate in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I'm facing an issue with self-signed certificate in Windows Phone 8 app. I have installed the certificate (.p7b) manually and it works fine when I browse through the site in **IEMobile**.

But when I visit the same, using the `WebBrowser` control in my hybrid app, The certificate error still shows and can't be ignored, even after tapping **Continue**. Isn't the Certificate installed System-wide or is it just for IE?

I have referred many links regarding this but in vain. Any help would be jighly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it turned out to be a hostname mismatch between what the certificate contained and the address I was using to connect to the server. If those match, and you install the P7B file on the Windows Phone device, then you should no longer see certificate warnings.

For the full details of my issues and solution, see this [thread on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/12143401-e486-42bf-8d16-2224233721b9/webbrowser-control-and-development-selfsigned-certificates?forum=wpdevelop).